# Kickstart create users and add to groups

Tags: centos, kickstart, anaconda

I'm doing a CentOS 8 automated install. I've previously had no problem creating a single user and adding it to a group like so:

```
user --name=othername --password=big_long_hash --iscrypted --groups=myname --homedir=/var/ftp --shell=/sbin/nologin
```

Despite documentation saying the group has to exist already, I've never had any issues.

Now I want to add multiple users to this group, so I add another line to my file

```
user --name=myname --groups=myname --homedir=/var/ftp --shell=/sbin/nologin
user --name=othername --password=big_long_hash --iscrypted --groups=myname --homedir=/var/ftp --shell=/sbin/nologin
```

And I get an error:

```
anaconda[1842]: program: Running... useradd -R /mnt/sysimage -U -G myname -d /var/ftp -m -s /sbin/nologin myname
useradd[25852]: failed adding user 'myname', exit code: 9
anaconda[1842]: program: useradd: group myname exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g.
anaconda[1842]: program: Return code: 9
anaconda[1842]: anaconda: kickstart.kickstart.user: User myname already exists
```

So I tried adding the line to create the group:

```
group --name=myname
user --name=myname --groups=myname --homedir=/var/ftp --shell=/sbin/nologin
user --name=othername --password=big_long_hash --iscrypted --groups=myname --homedir=/var/ftp --shell=/sbin/nologin
```

But no change. Tried not specifying the group:

```
group --name=myname
user --name=myname --homedir=/var/ftp --shell=/sbin/nologin
user --name=othername --password=big_long_hash --iscrypted --groups=myname --homedir=/var/ftp --shell=/sbin/nologin
```

This time the `useradd` command doesn't have the group in it, but still fails with the same error. I think I'm just going to work around it by calling `usermod` from the post-install script, but wanted to check if there's something I'm not understanding about adding groups and users in the Kickstart file.

Comment: What happens if you remove `--groups=myname` for the user `myname`. Useradd automatically creates the user-specific group.

Comment: Yeah, was just coming back to add that to my answer. No change.

Comment: Does `--groups` need to be `--groups=othername,myname`, so it sets the primary group as `othername` and treats the others as supplementary groups?

Answer (score 1):

I've never bothered with Kickstart's functionality for adding users or groups. I just do it myself in `%post`.

```
%post --erroronfail
groupadd groupname
useradd -m user1
useradd -m user2
usermod -a -G groupname user1
usermod -a -G groupname user2
```

Comment: Yup; as mentioned, that's what I'm doing as a workaround.

Comment: @miken32 And to be clear, I wouldn't bother trying to use it either.